# Centering Camera onto object

Tags: java, camera, 2d

I have a Camera class that basically follows the player around the map and keeps him centered on the screen. The math im applying works great until the scale(Zooming in and OUt) of the camera is altered. Here it is:

```
x = -cell.x - cell.mass/2 + Game.width/2 / sX; 
// Where x is the Camera's X, Cell is the Player and sX is the scale factor
```

I've been playing around with different equations but they all fail once the scale is altered. I can't seem to wrap my head around this and I could really use some insight on how to factor it in.

Here are some bits of the Camera Class:

```
public void set(Graphics bbg){
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)bbg;
   g2.translate(x, y);
   g2.scale(sX, sY);
 }

 public void unset(Graphics bbg){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)bbg;
    g2.translate(-x, -y);
 }

  public void scale(double sx, double sy){
   sX = sx;
   sY = sy;
  }

  public void Update(Cell cell){
    scale(0.9,0.9);
    x = -cell.x - cell.mass/2 + Game.width/2 / sX;
    y = -cell.y - cell.mass/2 + Game.height/2 / sY;
  }

  public double toWorldX(int x){
   return x - this.x / sX;
  }

  public double toWorldY(int y){
    return y - this.y / sY;
  }
```

[image: Scale is set to 1]
[image: Scale is set to 0.9]
The first image displays the result when the scale factor is 1(Normal Zoom). The second image displays the result  when the scale factor is 0.9(Zoomed Out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working equation for making the camera follow a player while factoring a scale factor is:

```
x =((cell.x + cell.mass * 0.5) - Game.width/sX * 0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a little difficulty in determining what some of your variables mean (such as cell.mass, I'm assuming it is the size) and I assume that Game.width is the actual width of the window. It would help to know what EXACTLY happen when the zoom is changed (like is the "center" of the zoom at a particular corner of the screen).

Now for an answer, without know what happens to the actual zoom... have you tried the addition of parenthesis like this...

```
x = ((cell.x + cell.mass/2) - Game.width/2) / sX;
```

or (because you use '-' a lot, I'm not sure how your coordinates work)

```
x = ((-cell.x - cell.mass/2) + Game.width/2) / sX;
```

Just an idea.

Comment: I provided pictures of what happens

Comment: Your method did not fix the issue

Comment: Could you provide the coordinates of the player and camera at zoom 1 and at some other zoom?

Comment: 1 Zoom:Camera: -1578.5408493893897 345.221003449922 Player: 2028.5408493893897 -45.221003449922044                                                   0.9 Zoom: Camera: -571.3988034281281 -584.088604619844 Player: 964.2589230853152 825.6797441578595

Comment: My apologies for not replying quickly; my internet has been down. I also apologize that I will likely no longer be able to assist you in solving your problem, because to effectively solve your problem (at least for me anyway) access to more source code would be required; I do not think that you would likely be willing to start posting a plethora of source code.

Comment: Well what would be the basic math for a camera to follow a player and keep the player centered while taking into account the scale factor of the camera?